# Does git use hardlinks for a remote on the same disk?

Tags: git, hardlink

I sometimes work with two sibling directories both containing the same repository. Using

```
git remote add sibling ../the-other-directory
```

I take over changes simply via

```
git fetch sibling
git cherry-pick sibling/a-branch
```

This is pretty practical, however I have a concern regarding hardlinks:

If the repositories share files, then crashing one of them could crash the other as well. A broken repository is something I've already experienced and I'm sure that saving a few megabytes and a few milliseconds is just not worth it.

- Does git use hardlinks when fetching from a repository on the same partition?
- If so, is there a way of preventing this (like `--no-hardlinks` for [git-clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))?

An additional advantage of not using hardlinks is having an additional backup which gets updated often without any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with the following script suggests that pseudo-cloning via `git init` + `git remote add` + `git fetch` doesn't create hardlinks to the source repository:

**hardlinktest**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
trap "rm -rf $tmpdir" EXIT
cd "$tmpdir"
set -x
git clone https://github.com/dictcp/awesome-git testrepo
git clone testrepo testrepo.localclone
mkdir testrepo.pseudoclone
cd testrepo.pseudoclone
git init
git remote add sibling ../testrepo
git fetch sibling
cd ..
ls -1 -i testrepo*/.git/objects/a0
```

**Relevant part of the output**:

```
$ ls -1 -i testrepo*/.git/objects/a0
testrepo/.git/objects/a0:
417590 cdfa472f2bf8212a02a3edeb941868d651749d

testrepo.localclone/.git/objects/a0:
417590 cdfa472f2bf8212a02a3edeb941868d651749d

testrepo.pseudoclone/.git/objects/a0:
537341 cdfa472f2bf8212a02a3edeb941868d651749d
```

This means that the file `testrepo.localclone/.git/objects/a0/cdfa472f2bf8212a02a3edeb941868d651749d` is a hardlink to `testrepo/.git/objects/a0/cdfa472f2bf8212a02a3edeb941868d651749d` - their inode values are the same (417590 for my test run, but your mileage will of course vary). The inode value (537341) of the corresponding file in the `testrepo.pseudoclone` repository tells us that it is an independent copy.

**Full output**:

```
$ ./hardlinktest 
+ git clone https://github.com/dictcp/awesome-git testrepo
Cloning into 'testrepo'...
remote: Counting objects: 58, done.
remote: Total 58 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 58
Unpacking objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
+ git clone testrepo testrepo.localclone
Cloning into 'testrepo.localclone'...
done.
+ mkdir testrepo.pseudoclone
+ cd testrepo.pseudoclone
+ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/tmp.ZWoH0OTA1P/testrepo.pseudoclone/.git/
+ git remote add sibling ../testrepo
+ git fetch sibling
remote: Counting objects: 58, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
remote: Total 58 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (58/58), done.
From ../testrepo
 * [new branch]      master     -> sibling/master
+ cd ..
+ ls -1 -i testrepo/.git/objects/a0 testrepo.localclone/.git/objects/a0 testrepo.pseudoclone/.git/objects/a0
testrepo/.git/objects/a0:
417590 cdfa472f2bf8212a02a3edeb941868d651749d

testrepo.localclone/.git/objects/a0:
417590 cdfa472f2bf8212a02a3edeb941868d651749d

testrepo.pseudoclone/.git/objects/a0:
537341 cdfa472f2bf8212a02a3edeb941868d651749d
+ rm -rf /tmp/tmp.ZWoH0OTA1P
```

Answer (score 1):

Git uses hard-links when you clone, but does not when you fetch. That is, when you add your remote via `git remote add foo ../somewhere` and then `git fetch foo`, you get copies, not hard-links.